# Fiddler localhost URLs (with port numbers) are not working in Visual Studio with IIS Express

Tags: localhost, multi-tenant, fiddler

We have a multi-tenant application.
This is an ASP .NET Core 2.1 project.
We use Visual Studio 2019

For local development with IIS Express we use URLs in the following format:

https://tenantA.contoso.com:4403/

https://tenantB.contoso.com:4403/

The above bindings are defined in applicationhost.config

Fiddler Everywhere v10.1  is rewriting the above URLs. So above URLs are not working and  application is not working in local development environment.

Is there a service/process we can stop while we run this Application?

**I am using Fiddler for the other project**

Please help!

Comment: If Fiddler changes the URLs shown in your question you should also include the URL after it has been changed by Fiddler. Also from your question it is not clear if those DNS names are local IIS servers or remote. Where are the DNS names like tenantA.contoso.com defined - in a custom DNS or using hosts file?

Comment: Robert, thank you for the reply. I actually did not note down the modified URLs (The above URLs/bindings are defined locally in applicationhost.config )in Fiddler. I stopped Fiddler and killed processes related to fiddler and now it is working fine.